# PerlQt - Can't use 'defined(@array)'

Tags: qt, perl

I am trying to create simple PerlQt app but when I start my Perl script I get this error:

```
Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/QtCore4.pm line 1420.
Compilation failed in require at ./perlqt.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./perlqt.pl line 5.
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use QtCore4;
use QtGui4;
use Window;

sub main
{
    my $app = Qt::Application( \@ARGV );

    if (!Qt::SystemTrayIcon::isSystemTrayAvailable()) {
        Qt::MessageBox::critical(0, Qt::Object::this->tr('Systray'),
                              Qt::Object::this->tr('I couldn\'t detect any system tray ' .
                                          'on this system.'));
        return 1;
    }
    Qt::Application::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(0);

    my $window = Window();
    $window->show();
    return $app->exec();
}

exit main();
```

Please how to fix it? I don't use any array in my code.

Comment: ...and remove the `defined` from the next two lines following line 1420 as well. Those three lines appear to be the only location where that specific error will be triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at QtCore4.pm line 1420.*

`QtCore4` does something that makes no sense. For now, it "works"—albeit noisly—but

```
@{$classinfos} = () if !defined @{$classinfos};
@{$signals} = () if !defined @{$signals};
@{$slots} = () if !defined @{$slots};
```

should be changed to

```
$classinfos ||= [];
$signals ||= [];
$slots ||= [];
```

in `QtCore4.pm`.

---

> *"SvREFCNT_inc" is not exported by the Devel::Peek module*
>   *Can't continue after import errors at QtGui4.pm line 25.*

This appears to be a bug in Devel::Peek. It used to export `SvREFCNT_inc`, and the docs still claims it does, but it doesn't anymore.

You can work around this by replacing

```
use Devel::Peek qw( SvREFCNT_inc );
```

with

```
use Devel::Peek qw( );
BEGIN { *SvREFCNT_inc = \&Devel::Peek::SvREFCNT_inc; }
```

in `QtGui4.pm`:

(Note, Perl code should never have to use `SvREFCNT_inc`, so its use a hack if not a bug!)

Comment: It helps, but I got another error: http://imgur.com/a/M6kKz Why is this Perl module so buggy?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Another error: http://imgur.com/a/qaVeI what is wrong with that PerlQt? You helped me.. but there are so many erros, Im thinking if PyQt is not better..

Comment: Seems like the module is not being actively maintained, added [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=121203)